# Forms Authentication Login on SQL Azure Reporting in Java

Tags: sql, azure, forms-authentication, reporting, http-post

I am trying to do a Http Post to automatically authenticate and login on Sql Azure and redirect to the report parameters webpage in Java.

For example,

Doing Httppost Login with the following url

https://INSTANCE.reporting.windows.net/ReportServer/logon.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2freportserver%2freportserver%3f%2fTMReport%2fAccounts&/TMReport/Accounts

which will redirect to the following url after successful authentication.

https://INSTANCE.reporting.windows.net/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/TMReport/Accounts

I want to ask

Q1: Is it possible to acheive forms authentication on SQL Azure with this way and If yes, how to do Http Post login SQL Azure reporting in Java?

Q2: How to obtain/save the authentication cookie(sqlAuthCookie) in Java when attempting to login to SQL Azure Report Server to provide authentication for the ReportViewer control?

Q3: Is there any way to use .Net ReportViewer Control in Java?

Q4: Please suggest alternatives to ReportViewer Control which can be used in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forms-Based Authentication with SQL Azure model uses the **SqlMembershipProvider** and the **SqlRoleProvider** to authenticate users of an ASP.NET web application that is hosted in Windows Azure against data that is stored in a SQL Azure database. Both The SqlMembershipProvider and the SqlRoleProvider shipped with the .NET Framework so will not work with Java. Same goes with .net ReportViewer control which is .net Framework based control and needs .net runtime to work and there is no equivalent way to use these (or any .net) control in Java.

Using Java for SQL Database (Previously known as SQL Azure) reporting you can use Crystal Reports which does work with Java.

Comment: Thanks, Avkash for the inputs. Can we use crystal reports on SQL Azure?

Comment: Yes it available with a few exceptions. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuredevelopment/thread/c99db398-4f01-4daa-afdf-8334a4dac5d6